# Angular 2/4 animate one item inside an array instead of all items

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-animations

I am trying to build some meaningful motion for a portfolio. The goal is when a user clicks on a job item, the item pop up and grow. To do that, I believe I have to change the state of the clicked element inside an array, but when I click it now, it affects all states of all elements inside the array animating all together. Can anyone explain me whats happening and how to fix?

**portfolio.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger,style,transition,animate,keyframes,state,query,stagger } from '@angular/animations';

export class Job {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

const JOBS: Job[] = [
  { id: 11, title: 'Item 1' },
  { id: 12, title: 'Item 2' },
  { id: 13, title: 'Item 3' },
];

@Component({
  selector: 'portfolio',
  templateUrl: './portfolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portfolio.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('enlarge', [
        state('small', style({
            height: '100px',
        })),
        state('large', style({
            height: '200px',
            background: 'red',
        })),
        transition('small <=> large', 
        animate('1s ease-in')),
    ]),

  ]
})

export class PortfolioComponent {
    title   = 'Portfolio';
    jobs    = JOBS;

    state: string = 'small'

    enlarge() {
        this.state = (this.state === 'small' ? 'large' : 'small');
    }
}
```

**portfolio.component.html**

```
<div class="list" 
*ngFor='let job of jobs'
[@enlarge]='state'
(click)="enlarge()">
    <div for="#">{{job.id}} - {{job.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some external help and research I figured out the solution to my problem.

**portfolio.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger,style,transition,animate,keyframes,state,query,stagger } from '@angular/animations';

export class Job {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  state: string;
}   

@Component({
  selector: 'portfolio',
  templateUrl: './portfolio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./portfolio.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('enlarge', [
        state('small', style({
            height: '100px',
            transform: 'translateY(0)',
        })),
        state('large', style({
            height: '200px',
            transform: 'translateY(-300px)',
            background: 'red'
        })),
    ]),

  ]
})

export class PortfolioComponent {
    title   = 'Portfolio';

    jobs = [
        { id: 11, title: 'Item 1', state: 'small' },
        { id: 12, title: 'Item 2', state: 'small' },
        { id: 13, title: 'Item 3', state: 'small' },
    ];

    enlarge(index) {
        index.state = (index.state === 'small' ? 'large' : 'small');

    }
}
```

**portfolio.component.html**

```
<div class="list" 
*ngFor='let job of jobs'
[@enlarge]='job.state'
(click)="enlarge(job)">
    <div for="#">{{job.id}} - {{job.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really, I just noticed you took my answer and posted it as yours with some small change

Comment: Well, the two years younger me giving a try on Angular, asked for help, you tried to help, your solution didn't work (probably because of me, not arguing that), and you stopped answering. I kept searching and trying solutions for hours until I found a solution with an example somewhere else and managed to make it work for my case. I am sorry you feel that way, but your solution didn't solve the problem at the time and you stopped answering. Indeed the solution ended up quite similar to yours. I couldn't do it at the time, but I can upvote your answer now. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if its still relevant to you or not, but the thing is that the first answer missed the point to create a field in original data for the state and then try the map function. 
Now my question is that why should I store the state of html element along with the data? it it not too stupid?

Answer (score 3):

Currently you assign the same state using the same variable to all items. What you need to do is to assign different state to each item.

1. Set a default state for all items:

   ```
   this.jobs = this.jobs.map((job) => {
     job.state = "small";
     return job;
   });
   ```
2. Update your template:

Set `[@enlarge]='state'` to `[@enlarge]='job.state'`

3. Update your `enlarge()` method:

   ```
   enlarge(index) {
   let job = this.jobs[index].state;
   job = (job === 'small' ? 'large' : 'small');
        }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but where should I put the step 1 code? I tried to put it in my class but I received an error: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

Comment: Try the updated code @OsmarMatos. Put it after your get your list of jobs..

Comment: Tried but now the error is Property 'state' does not exist on type 'Job' on screen and  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined on console - @TheUnreal

Comment: why store the html element state along with the data coming from some other source, which mostly is not going to be an array of objects in the code. It does not make any sense.